# How to grant Android studio acces for opening androidSDK in C:\Program Files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I'm an absolute Android beginner, I just downloaded android studio and I tried to launch my first Android project ever. However, for some reason I can't launch the android studio emulator.

The error i'm getting is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AndroidSDK\tools\emulator.exe" -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,file=C:\Program Files (x86)\AndroidSDK/system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\/system.img: could not open disk image C:\Program Files (x86)\AndroidSDK/system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\/system.img: Could not open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AndroidSDK/system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\/system.img': Permission denied
```

If I understand correctly the emulator can't get permissions to the system images without administrator rights since the SDK(image-files) are located under my C:\Program Files(x86) directory.

**Q: Is there a way to easily give permissions to these files? 
If not..
Can I just switch my AndroidSDK folder to another location without messing other things up?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running the IDE in admin mode? If you're on Windows you can right-click and run as administrator.